# Steam has a problem with my Nvidia diver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, steam, jockey

I'm having some difficulty with Steam.  I installed the proprietary driver using Additional Drivers, and up until now, thought it had installed correctly. All my desktop effects worked flawlessly.

But, when I tried to run steam, it said, `"OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems"`.

So, I thought that perhaps I hadn't installed the driver yet.  Opening Additional drivers, it shows **Nvidia 3.10**, but says that `"This driver has been actived, but is not in use"`  Trying to launch Portal, is says it couldn't find the `"required entry point 'gelGetError'"`.

So, as far as I can tell, Steam thinks that I don't have the propietary driver installed.  But, when I open Nvida X Server settings, it clearly says I have driver 3.10.

Can anyone please tell me what's going?

EDIT: Sorry for taking so long to respond, as requested, here is the result of running "lsmod | grep nv"

```
     nvidia     9410995  52
```

Comment: Try re-installing and driver, you probably have a mis-match between Xorg drive and GLX versions. With X running also add the content of `lsmod | grep nv` to you post.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, though with an AMD card
What fixed it for me was this:

```
sudo usermod -a -G video <username>
```

and then rebooting.

**Explanation**

Per default the user is not allowed to use direct write because he is not member of the video group

Comment: Already tried this, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

after you install the Nvidia driver,make sure you have the nvidia-current package installed, it is the main package for the driver and without it your driver won't work.

thanks.

Comment: I installed nvidia-current, and it removed the 3.10 driver, and installed 3.04.  Regardless, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

edit your /etc/modprobe.conf, and add the following:

> install nvidia

it should work then

Comment: My system doesn't have a /etc/modprobe.conf file.  It does have a /etc/modprobe.d/ folder, though.  But inside it is several conf files.  Should I edit anything there?